# How to connect odbc database using codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter

```
$active_group = 'default';
$query_builder = TRUE;

$db['default'] = array(
    'dsn'   => 'tes',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',
    'password' => '',
    'database' => 'tes',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
);
```

When I run the program there is an error:

> " Message: Call to undefined method CI_DB_odbc_driver::select() Filename: models/m_city.php"

**m_city.php file:**

```
<?php

class m_city extends CI_Model
{
    function get_all($where = array())
    {
        $this->db->select('Name,Population');
        $this->db->where($where);
        $this->db->limit('50');
        $query = $this->db->get('City');
        return $query->result_array();
    }
}
```

I already made dsn name on odbc. the name of dsn is "tes".

Comment: already edited. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

If you use "Mysql" then follow the following instructions.
Please put database username and database password in the following:

```
$active_group = 'default';
    $query_builder = TRUE;

    $db['default'] = array(

    'dsn'   => '',
    'hostname' => 'localhost',
    'username' => '',//Put database username
    'password' => '',// put database password
    'database' => 'tes',
    'dbdriver' => 'odbc',
    'dbprefix' => '',
    'pconnect' => FALSE,
    'db_debug' => (ENVIRONMENT !== 'production'),
    'cache_on' => FALSE,
    'cachedir' => '',
    'char_set' => 'utf8',
    'dbcollat' => 'utf8_general_ci',
    'swap_pre' => '',
    'encrypt' => FALSE,
    'compress' => FALSE,
    'stricton' => FALSE,
    'failover' => array(),
    'save_queries' => TRUE
    );
```

After complete this save the page and open the page 'autoload.php' under the config folder. There search "$autoload['libraries']" option. Put the following

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database');
```

If  you use  PDO, PostgreSQL, Oracle then see the following links:

https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/configuration.html

Comment: <?php

$con=odbc_connect("tes", "", ""); // dsn tes, username pass empty
if($con)
{
 echo "Connected<br>";
}
else
{
 echo "Failed";
}

$sql="select * from City";
$result=odbc_exec($con, $sql);
while ($row=odbc_fetch_array($result)) {
echo "City: ". $row['Name'];
echo "Population : ". $row['Population'];
echo "<br/>";
}

?>

it will be successfull.. i just confused when I want to connect using CodeIgniter.